# Bind a property of a resource to the viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, resources, wpf-controls

I have an `IValueConverter` that I've added a dependency property to because I need the viewmodel to set the property.

```
public class ParameterValueToString: ContentControl, IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value
                         , Type targetType
                         , object parameter
                         , CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Converter.ToString(value); //Throws NullReferenceException
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value
                             , Type targetType
                             , object parameter
                             , CultureInfo culture)
    {
        /* convert back */
    }

    internal const string ConvertPropertyName = "Converter";

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ConverterProperty 
        = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(ConvertPropertyName
                                             , typeof(IParameterConverter)
                                             , typeof(ParameterValueToString));

    public IParameterConverter Converter
    {
        get { return (IParameterConverter) GetValue(ConverterProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ConverterProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

The property is an object that does the conversion from `ParameterValue` to `string`. I'm trying to reuse code.

The VM has a property of `IParameterConverter` called `ParameterConverter`.

The WPF I've setup:

```
<Namespace:ParameterValueToString x:Key="pvts" Converter="{Binding ParameterConverter}"/>
```

But when I try to use the `Converter` property I get a `NullReferenceException`.

The end use for the converter is to convert a list of `ParameterValue` into a string (and turn that string back into a list). This is to make is easy for the user to enter the values: as a newline separated list.

How can I get the converter to use `IParameterConverter`?

Comment: Apparently the DataContext is not inherited to the ParameterValueToString instance. You also have to explicitly specify the source object of the `ParameterConverter` binding by setting its `Source` or `RelativeSource` property.

Comment: I would like to know your ultimate goal of this solution, may be an alternative in much simpler to implement. Can you use an ordinary converter? Usually need a converter to convert the value, and not to set the property to `ViewModel`.